# How open Certificate Snap-In from .NET

Tags: .net, x509, mmc

I'm building an application to sign files using X509 Certificates.

Users can check the "Certificate Path", the entire intermediate certificates of the choosen one (all Authorities).

I would like to allow users to click over some of these intermediate Certs and open the Windows' Certificate window (I guess it's a MMC extension).

I know we can call MMC using Process.Start("mmc") but which type of parameters I have to pass to open the Certificate Window showing this specific certificate?

I would appreciate any help on it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate

Comment: Thanks Lex!  Great!